# $n$-number of creation operators on the ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-states

I simply want to prove the following:

for the given state, $|n\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}(a^\dagger)^n|0\rangle$, show that this satisfies $\hat{N}|n\rangle = n|n\rangle$ given $\hat{N} = \hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}$.

Now, I have shown that this is normalized as $\langle n|m \rangle = \delta_{n,m}$ so that's fine, and I even know (via induction) that $[\hat{a},(\hat{a}^\dagger)^n] = n(\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n-1}$, so what (in the world) am I missing. I think my issue is recovering $|n\rangle$ to get $n|n\rangle$ in the end. Any hints or direct proofs/help is appreciated (I have been trying this problem longer then I wish to admit...)

Thanks!

Comment: Just act with $\hat{N}$ on the state, use the commutator identity you've shown, and combine the remaining $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ with the $(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^{n-1}$ to make a $(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^n$, and you're done.

Comment: Consider to use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >. I've done that for you now.

Comment: .... I actually had @march result, but never noticed the grouping of $n \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}(a^\dagger)^n| n\rangle\right)$ after using the fact of $a| n\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Can you write your own answer to your question, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question (with the help of @march and @jason-funderberker), simply perform the following:
$$ \hat{N}|n\rangle = \hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}|n\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\hat{a}^\dagger\left(\hat{a}(\hat{a}^\dagger)^n\right)|0\rangle $$

Then plug-in the commutator relationship from the question above,

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\left(\hat{a}^\dagger n(\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n-1} + \hat{a}^\dagger(\hat{a}^\dagger)^n\hat{a}\right)|0\rangle = n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}(\hat{a}^\dagger)^n|0\rangle\right) = n|n\rangle, $$
where in the last line we used the fact that $a|0\rangle = 0$. Thanks again!